# How to make text follow this square as it is being moved around?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this jsfiddle where one can move a square with the mouse.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/3kwwo53t/2/

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like some text say, `"Square"` to appear beside the white square. As this white square is being moved around, the text `"Square"` follows the white square. Is this possible? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/13/

Comment: @Pranav C Balan, I don't believe it. You're so fast! You make me feel stupid. Please put it down as an answer. Could you indicate which part you modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this byy putting a `span` inside which is absolute positioned

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.directive('ngDraggable', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var startX, startY, x = 0,
        y = 0,
        start, stop, drag, container;

      var width = elem[0].offsetWidth,
        height = elem[0].offsetHeight;

      // Obtain drag options
      if (scope.dragOptions) {
        start = scope.dragOptions.start;
        drag = scope.dragOptions.drag;
        stop = scope.dragOptions.stop;
        var id = scope.dragOptions.container;
        if (id) {
          container = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
        }
      }

      // Bind mousedown event
      elem.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        startX = e.clientX - elem[0].offsetLeft;
        startY = e.clientY - elem[0].offsetTop;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (start) start(e);
      });

      // Handle drag event
      function mousemove(e) {
        y = e.clientY - startY;
        x = e.clientX - startX;
        setPosition();
        if (drag) drag(e);
      }

      // Unbind drag events
      function mouseup(e) {
        $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (stop) stop(e);
      }

      // Move element, within container if provided
      function setPosition() {
        if (container) {
          if (x < container.left) {
            x = container.left;
          } else if (x > container.right - width) {
            x = container.right - width;
          }
          if (y < container.top) {
            y = container.top;
          } else if (y > container.bottom - height) {
            y = container.bottom - height;
          }
        }

        elem.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left: x + 'px'
        });
      }
    }
  }

})

.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dragOptions = {
    start: function(e) {
      console.log("STARTING");
    },
    drag: function(e) {
      console.log("DRAGGING");
    },
    stop: function(e) {
      console.log("STOPPING");
    },
    container: 'container'
  }

});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions'><span style="position:relative;left:100%;top:0;color:red">hi</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only place you modified is the html. `<span style="position:relative;left:100%;top:0;color:red">hi</span>` Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a pseudo-element:

```
.shape:before {
   content: "Square";
}
```

This will insert some content (in this case the string "square") before the .square element in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple way

```
{
    content: "Square"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Where this code should be placed? This is a comment not an answer!